# Probability question: why is $P(X \leq 1, 3 <Y \leq 4) = P(X \leq 1, Y \leq 4) - P(X \leq 1, Y \leq 3)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X,Y$ be random variables. Can someone explain why

$P(X \leq 1, 3 <Y \leq 4) = P(X \leq 1, Y \leq 4) - P(X \leq 1, Y \leq 3)$

Intuitively, it makes sense, but I'm struggling to prove it with set theory and probability axioms.

Comment: What you've written is false as stated; do you mean for the right-hand side to have $Y \leq 4$ and $Y < 3$ instead?

Comment: @MarcusM Yes, I edited. Thanks

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Nothing about independence was mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because we have the set identity $$\{x \leq 1, 3 < y \leq 4\} = \{x \leq 1, y \leq 4\} \setminus \{x \leq 1, y \leq 3\}.$$

EDIT: where we write $A \setminus B$ means $A \cap B^c$ for $B \subseteq A$.

Comment: Yeah, I should have been more specific about that (I only write set-minus for subsets, otherwise it's intersection with complement)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$ A=\{(x,y):(0\le x \le 1, 3\le y \le 4)$$

is a rectangle bounded by $x=1$,$y=3$, and $y=4$

$$ B=\{(x,y):(0\le x \le 1, 0\le y \le 4)$$

is a rectangle bounded by $x=1$,$y=0$, and $y=4$

$$ C=\{(x,y):(x \le 1, 0\le y < 3)$$

is a rectangle bounded by $x=1$,$y=0$, and $y=3$

As you see $$ B=A\cup C$$ and $$A\cap C = \phi $$

Thus $$P(X \le 1, 3 <Y \le 4) = P(X \le 1, 4 \le Y) - P(X \le 1, 3 \le Y)$$

Answer (score 0):

Because $(-\infty,3 ]\times (3,4]$ and $(-\infty ,3]\times (-\infty ,3]$ are disjoints.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/994286)

Comment: This of course answer totally to the question (of course If you know the lowest basis in probabilities). @BjörnFriedrich

Answer (score 0):

Using only $\cap$ and disjoint sets:

$P(X \leq 1 \cap Y \leq 4)  = P((X \leq 1 \cap  3 <Y \leq 4) \cap (X \leq 1 \cap  Y \leq 3) )  $

The 2 sets are disjoints so this is equal to:

$= P(X \leq 1 \cap  3 <Y \leq 4)  + P(X \leq 1 \cap  Y \leq 3 )$

Therefore

$$P(X \leq 1 \cap  3 <Y \leq 4) = P(X \leq 1 \cap Y \leq 4) - P(X \leq 1 \cap  Y \leq 3 )$$